# How to call a Specific Folder in Javascript/Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

I've created a combo ajax select menu and am running it on localhost. I just tried to move the files into a wordpress config setting it up as a template, but I'm having a problem because of the path for the .js file to call other files.

Is there a way I can call a direct path? The JS looks like this:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("select#direction").attr("disabled","disabled");
        $("select#route").change(function(){
        $("select#direction").attr("disabled","disabled");
        $("select#direction").html("<option>wait...</option>");
        var id = $("select#route option:selected").attr('value');
        $.post("select_direction.php", {id:id}, function(data){
            $("select#direction").removeAttr("disabled");
            $("select#direction").html(data);
        });
    });
});
```

I'd like to call it from the wordpress theme folder/includes/select_direction.php

This JS file exists in the includes folder as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the path from the websites document root directly to the file you want to call. May be something like:

```
"/theme_folder/includes/select_direction.php"
```

Any path that begins with a slash "/" will be a path originating from your document root. If the path is relative to your the page your JavaScript code is on, you can use dot-dot ".." to mean up one directory:

```
"../../theme-folder/includes/select_direction.php"
```

If you want to pass this path from your PHP script, the best option would be to put the path in an HTML element attribute:

```
<body data-script-path="/theme_folder/includes/select_direction.php">
```

Then in your JavaScript code you can get the path with:

```
var path = $("body").data("script-path");
```

There are many ways to pass data from the server side to the client side, you could parse the JavaScript with PHP -- but that is an ugly solution. HTML5 data attributes are much cleaner.

Comment: Thanks. It worked by going straight to the root folder and going up the folder chain. I was looking for something more where I can call a part of PHP in the .js script but since that's not possible, (at least I don't think it is), I'll just manually edit the files when needed. Thanks for taking the time to help out.

Answer (score -1):

The JavaScript code does not know it is in the includes folder. It runs where ever the page it is running on is located.

So you would reference files like you would with any relative path from where the page is located.

Comment: Is there a way to select the direct path? If so, how would I go about doing so? like a /wp-content/themes/etc/etc/includes/file_name.php